# How to change the dom in javascript from SVG to HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

So I have some Javascript and SVG embedded in my HTML page

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Channel Guide</title>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="guide.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center">
    <embed id="svgtag" src="guide.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="850" height="700" /> 
</body>
```

When I load the SVG file it calls a Javascript function in the js file called load()

```
function load(evt) {
    svgdoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;      
    fillData();
}
```

I can now use svgdoc to change the SVG DOM.
The problem is that I want to change something in the HTML file, the width of the embedded SVG doc, using the Javascript file. However the document variable points to guide.svg.

How do I edit the HTML file, or open it in a new DOM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the html window by using either the [parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.parent) or [top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.top) objects. So top.document would be the html document etc.